# Samsung 2955 laser prints error pages before and after printing document - Invalid page range: none printer-location= marker-level 52

Tags: printing, google-chrome, libreoffice, pdf, samsung

I have two printers connected to my network. One is a Samsung C1860FW. The other is a Samsung M-2955ND.Both are on the same network. I've been running Ubuntu since 2009. Currently I'm running 20.04LTS. The C1860FW is working fine. About 2 months ago an issue started with the M-2955ND. It has been in use with Ubuntu for 7 to 8 years without issue until now.When I print from anything associated with Googl, a Gmail or any document with the Google Suite of apps, I first get a page saying (on individual lines)
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none printer-location- marker-levels=52

Then the document prints on a new page. Then I get a final page that says:
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none printer-location- marker-levels=52
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none
Invalid page range: none printer-location- marker-levels=52

In other words, the last page has the same thing printed on it as the first page, except it is repeated twice. It I print pdf documents or LibreOffice documents straight from my hard drive, they print fine. The issue is only with anything printed through Google, including Google Drive, and only with the M-2955ND. I was running Ubuntu 18.04LTS when the issue started. Two weeks later I upgraded to 20.04LTS. That didn't change anything so it doesn't appear to be a Ubuntu version issue. I did send an issue problem report to Chrome support, but I didn't get any reply.

I don't know if something changed with the driver for this printer since HP now owns the Samsung printers, or if something changed in cups, or if something changed in Google. I hate to throw away a printer that has been super dependable, has great print quality and speed, and has worked perfectly for years until now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems primarily Samsung (and Ricoh) printers are having this issue with Chrome. With my Samsung Xpress M2825ND - same issue. Have you tried with using the system dialog as suggested in the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the same problem here but I have a Ricoh printer. Used to print fine but recently prints an Invalid page before and after from ONE of my Ubuntu PCs.

Other Ubuntu PCs still print fine to it.

I have found it only does it from Chrome print preview. Using Chrome print using system dialog works fine.

I removed the printer and readded it and thought it solved it, but the problem is now back (or maybe it never went away...)

Work arounds:

- Use Firefox
- Use Chrome but use Ctrl+Shift+P or select the print using system dialog option
- Change Chrome to use System Dialog by default

  - Various options googled, there used to be a setting in chrome://flags/ but that seems to have gone. There used to be a `--disable-print-preview`﻿ argument to chrome that used to work, but now does not (though see next point).
  - The answer after some more googling (can't find the reference page now), is use `--args --disable-print-preview` when starting Chrome.
  - To make it stick, this is what I did:

    - `cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
    - Edit `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and add `--args --disable-print-preview` to the end (but before the `%U`) of any `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` lines
    - I actually renamed `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and appended _old to it but not sure if that is required as I thought that the ones in `~/.local/share/applications` took precedence... maybe it would have after a reboot, so you could try without renaming first...
    - Reboot for good measure (I could not recall the command to force a reload of the desktop shortcuts so rebooted, also I removed my favourite shortcut and re-added it, before rebooting, not sure if that was required).
  - Chrome now starts and prints without print-preview which means we don't get an extra two pages printed for every chrome print...

Answer (score 1):

I've started experiencing the same thing with my Samsung M2875FW printer. It's only just started, but that might be because of the change from Google cloudprint to direct printing. I can work around it by using "Print using system dialog" in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing same issue here with my Samsung SCX-4729FW.
When I stop my spooler (cupsdisable Samsung-SCX-472x) and print a PDF from chrome. I see the job in the queue.
When I use the command line lineprinter to print exactly the same job ("lp -d Samsung-SCX-472x -o psdebug d00028-001") I see then 2 jobs in the queue. After enabling the queue again. I get the first job printed with these additional pages and the 2nd job printed without such pages.

the workaround is working also on my side.
When using the "Print using system dialog" in chrome, no additional pages where print. Seams to be a bug inside Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with a Samsung ML-2955ND. The extra pages occur when printing from google-chrome or chromium. A work-around is to print to a pdf file and then go into one of the pdf utilities and print the file. This eliminates the extra pages. I'm using Ubuntu 20.10.

I noticed this problem does not occur when using google-chrome and sending output to the same printer on a Mac running Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was being tracked by crbug.com/1156941.

According to the bug, it *should* be fixed as of Chrome version 95.0.4632.0. Would anyone mind confirming?

Comment: I presently have Chrome 95.0.4638.54 running on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I still have the same problem. I tried both printing a portion of this thread, and also a spreadsheet in Google docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the google chrome version listed above. The problem doesn't occur in chromium-94. Also, I'm currently running Fedora 34 with a 5.14.xx kernel. I decided to try running Fedora 34 to see if this problem persists. It disappeared with the 5.14 kernel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178687)